# fnAddData() in datatable adds to same row instead of adding to new rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, datatable

I've a xml String which I need to display in datatable based on that xml data..

```
var xml = "<Users><user><username>user</username><password>password</password></user><user><username>user1</username><password>password1</password></user><user><username>user2</username><password>password2</password></user></users>";  //this is a sample, but in reality I'm getting the xml string from server
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);  //parsing xml to valid xml document
var $events = $(xmlDoc).find("Users");   

var thisTable;
thisTable = $("#user-data").dataTable(      //user-data is the id of my table
    {
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI": true
   }
);

$events.each(function(index, event){
    console.log('test');
    var $event = $(event),
    addData = [];
    addData.push( $event.children("loan").children("user").children("username").text());
    addData.push($event.children("user").children("password").text());
    thisTable.fnAddData(addData);
});
```

This was based on the demo present here

http://jsfiddle.net/jqbv2/

But I'm having a very strange issue, in my console, "test" gets printed only one time, so the each is iterating just only one time. Also in my table, all the usernames are displayed in first row's username field and all the passwords are displayed in first row's password field. To say, the data I'm using in relatime time is entirely different and this is just an example for that. This is the table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="loan-data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I cant figure out why does all the datas are added to a single row which is mainly due to the fact that `.each` is iterated just only one no matter how much list of datas are present. It works perfectly in the fiddle example, but when I try it with some modification, I'm getting this conflict..

Comment: What does `$events` contain. Have you tried to write the content of that object to the console?

Comment: @Mouser, loans, prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "Loans", jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function , this is the first line displayed in my chrome console, if you're wondering about loans, that is what my data is, it's like a different content, which have lots of nested properties

Comment: Well there you go. It contains only one object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This updated `each` should do the trick:

```
var eventChildren = $event.children("loan");
eventChildren.each(function(index, event){
    console.log('test');
    var $event = $(event),
    addData = [];
    addData.push( $event.children("user").children("username").text());
    addData.push($event.children("user").children("password").text());
    thisTable.fnAddData(addData);
});
```

`loan` contains children with *nodeName* `user`. So we need to iterate over `loan` and not over the document root.

Comment: It works.. And much thanks for your explanation. I just started understanding how it's working..

Comment: I like to add class to my <tr> tag like <tr class="odd gradex">, is there any way I can add it?

Comment: @user1354678, I would do that in CSS. Use this: `#loan-data > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #c3c3c3;}` This will add a background color to all rows that are odd.